# ¿Problema con imagen Nine-Patch en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

Tengo este código XML para la interfaz de la APP:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:background="@drawable/fondo"**
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bienvenido"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/estilos_boton"
                android:text="@string/boton"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Donde el BACKGROUND de mi RELATIVE LAYOUT es una imagen PNG sin alteración alguna, al momento de correrlo en el emulador y en mi celular todas las demás etiquetas aparecen perfectamente tal y como están el código XML, el problema viene cuando modifico la imagen con la herramienta de android NINE-PATCH, modifico algunas cosas para que mi imagen se redimencione dependiendo de las resoluciones de cada dispositivo, en la vista previa de Android Studio todo se comporta de igual manera que cuando pongo el fondo sin edición, pero al momento de correr la app en mi teléfono o emulador este me arroja un resultado completamente distinto algo como esto:

[image: resultado al correr la app con la imagen NINE-PATCH]

Si no aparece la imagen explico mas o menos como aparece.

se muestra la pantalla con el fondo con la imagen nine patch y ensequida aparece el palabra "Bienvenido" de esta manera

B
ie
nv
e
ni
(ESTO DE FORMA VERTICAL)

solo aparece eso y no alcanza a aparecer el botón. PORF FAVOR NECESITO AYUDA YA QUE YA HE AGOTADO MIS IDEAS, CREE OTRO PROYECTO PARA EMPEZAR DESDE CERO Y NADA, CAMBIE DE EMULADOR, Y NADA LO CORRI EN MI CELULAR Y NADA, YA NO SE QUE HACER

Esta es una captura de mi archivo nine patch
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: recuerdo esta pregunta, me podrías asegurar que la aplicación tiene el mismo comportamiento en un dispositivo físico? si esto es así podrías agregar el código de tu Actividad y si es posible tu Drawable 9-patch, saludos.

Comment: No realizo nada en la actividad la dejo tal y como se crea de esta manera.

`package com.miprimerproyectoandroid.karolcampos.miprimerproyectoandroid;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}`

Comment: Kenneth, tu Draw 9 Patch no tiene guias, me parece que no es un archivo correcto, podrías subirlo en algún lugar.

Comment: Como que no tiene guias? no entiendo, podrias ser mas especifico, o como quieres ver que ponga el archivo nine-patch?

Comment: Si ves la documentación http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/draw9patch.html  se requieren unas lineas de guía, las cuales sirven para expandir la imagen. Puedes subir en alguna parte el archivo para revisarlo a detalle.

Comment: Aaaa si, y en la imagen que puse si se ven las lineas de guía chacla bien, en la parte de afuera de la imagen tanto en la parte superior izquierda como en la derecha puedes ver esas lineas de guia.